# Update a SpreadSheet with the google API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update a given spreadsheet cell, using node.js googleapis v4 and authorizing with a JWT client.

Reading works fine, but I cannot understand how to write:

```
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
                auth: this._auth,
                spreadsheetId: this._metaData.spreadSheetId,
                range: range,
                valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
            },(err, resp) => {

                if (err) {
                    console.log('Data Error :', err)
                    reject(err);
                }

                resolve(resp);

            });

        });
```

How do I specify the data, and how do I pass it to the call?

I understand I should use a ValueRange object, but how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After better reviewing the (poor) documentation, I inferred that you had to pass a request object in the call:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
    {
      auth: this._auth,
      spreadsheetId: this._metaData.spreadSheetId,
      range: "Sheet1!A1",
      valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
      resource: { range: "Sheet1!A1", majorDimension: "ROWS", values: [["b"]] },
    },
    (err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Data Error :", err);
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(resp);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Where did the 'resource' field come from?!?! I tried everything prior to that. 'values,data,..etc. etc.'  'resource' is nowhere in the documentation.  Anyway... it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: @justinP I had to read the source code to understand what the library was doing

Comment: Had no idea there was a 'resource' field! Thanks.

Comment: @Mascarpone 
When I tried to call that API, I am getting below error.
"The API returned an error: Error: Request had insufficient authentication scopes"
I need your help for this. Thanks

Comment: @PhonegapExpert when you create the authentication token you should specify the permissions you need.